# Simple thing for Angular 7.1.3 work ? Bind Onclick event by class name ? is that work?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using Angular 7.1.3,  I am familiar with Jquery.

I just need simple to add `active` class in my sidebar for `onclick` event

```
<a class="sidebar-link" routerLink="/foo">foo</a>
<a class="sidebar-link" routerLink="/voo">Voo</a>
<a class="sidebar-link" routerLink="/moo">Moo</a>
```

so onlclick I need to add active class. I do not want to add `(click)="onClick(active)"` in every link. I mean let set it simple get element by class name and bind on-click event and add class.

Is there simple way to bind like in jquery I need this simple way:

```
$('.sidebar-link').on('click', e => {
          $(this).addClass('active');
      });
```

I googled it for but in every where they need to add `(click)="onClick(active)"` in every link.

so this Simple thing for Angular 7.1.3 is work in less code?

How can I add `active` class by class name in Angular 7.1.3?

Comment: Check this mate, https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use RouterLinkActive directory for this, when your page rounter link is as you described in your routerLink tag, the routerLinkActive classes will be added the class property of your HTML template.

You can find more examples here,  https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="class1 class2">Bob</a>
<a routerLink="/user/bob" [routerLinkActive]="['class1', 'class2']">Bob</a>
```

Comment: Yes that perfect what I need, its simple and fast. thanks